# How to create a junction table with 2 parent tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a requirement to link 2 tables to the same lookup table with one to many relationship. I need a junction table but this junction table will hang off of 2 parent tables I'm not sure how to accomplish it. ProjectNumber can be the same number in Projects and Bids

```
Projects
ProjectNumber PK

Bids
ProjectNumber PK

EndclientJunction
ProjectNumber PK, FK - FK to projectnumber in Projects
EndClientId PK, FK - FK to EndclientId in EndClients

Endclients
EndclientId PK
Name
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Looks nice like it is. What are your constraints ? May an EndClientId have as many ProjectNumber as they want ? This structure will also allow a project to be in junction with more than one EndclientId, is it that what you need ?

Comment: @Louis ProjectNumber in Bids and Projects can be the same number. Thats the issue.  I thought about adding another column to EndclientJunction called BidOrProject and make that part of the composite key

Comment: What happens if a ProjectNumber is in Projects AND in Bids ? Best solution will be to build a view that joins both tables, but you must first define what would happen when the key is in both tables (which one is in the view) to make it easy to use.